# Can anyone show me how I can just extract and display the text in the image on Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, text, display

Can some one please show me how to extract only the text in the red square?
I have been fiddling around with python and tried to extract it with no success.
I am writing a script that asks you to enter an address, then fires up Firefox (or Chrome) goes to google website and searches the travel time and distance from the address already saved in the python script. I just need the text in the red square to be displayed as plain text in the command screen.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, so far what I have tried is below, I just don't know how to access the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time




print("Please type in address")
address = input()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = r"https://www.google.com"
driver.get(url)

ara = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

ara.send_keys("Navigate to "+ address + " "+"from terror st keilor park" + Keys.RETURN)

x = driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='exp0']/div[1]/div/div[@class='BbbuR uc9Qxb uE1RRc']")

print(x.text)
```

[google maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rGhl.jpg)

Comment: This is not a free code service. Please show what you have tried, what happened vs expectation and we can help.

Comment: I am new to the site and as stated trying to learn python. I apologise for not giving much information or the code. I have edited the post which now includes the full code i was trying,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` and wait for the element to `element_to_be_clickable` and use the following `xpath`.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@data-rre-id="exp0"]')))
print(element.text)
```

To execute above code you need to imports followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the google maps API to directly pull the data from google in python without having to open a browser, take an image, and then process that image to read the text and and and...

Or, this isn't recommended but may work, send a request through python code to retrieve the web page and parse the response.

Google "python requests examples" to learn how to make web requests in python code.

Then google "python parse html" and learn to parse web pages with code to extract the information you're looking for.

There are plenty of ways to get the information you're looking for, but the easiest sure wont be by using optical character recognition on an image.  But, if your dead set on that, google "python optical character recognition".

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I will look into your suggestions. I did look into Google maps api but because I require travel time and distance to be displayed I had to use the Directions api which after some searches requires you to start paying.  I have written a script where you enter the address and searches for travel times from 4 different locations at once hence it takes its toll on "the bonus credit" that Google gives you (unless I am missing something) The whole idea is to get travel times and distance from 4 different locations which I will add to the script so it can compare.